# Azure DevOps REST Api: Does git commit exists in branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a commit id and need to check in which branch(es) the commits contains. I've tried some approaches, but no one fits...

My best idea was:

```
var existsInBranch = (await gitClient.GetCommitsAsync(projectId, repositoryId, new GitQueryCommitsCriteria
{
    Ids = new List<string>
    {
        commits[0].CommitId
    },
    CompareVersion = new GitVersionDescriptor()
    {
        VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch,
        VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None,
        Version = "main"
    }
})).Any();
```

But this will end with an exception: `The value specified for the following variable must be null: compareVersion.`.

Are there some other ways to get the information? The Azure DevOps UI has this feature:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature: "Search for commit in branches and tags" exists in the preview features. Based on my test（check with backend API in Browser）, I am afraid there is no direct way to achieve this function outside the UI interface

> Are there some other ways to get the information?

Of course. I would like to share two methods:

1.You could use PowerShell to Run the RestApis and compare the result:

[Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#refs-heads)

[Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Here is a PowerShell script example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepoId}/refs?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$id= "commitid"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

ForEach($Branch in $response.value.name)
{
  
   $Branch -match "refs/heads/(?<content>.*)"


   $BranchName = $matches['content']

   echo $BranchName

   $url1= "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectNAME}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepoID}/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=$($BranchName)&api-version=6.0"

   $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json


    
   if ($response2.value.commitid.contains($id))

   {
     echo "$BranchName contains the commit"

   }
   else
   {
     echo "$BranchName doesn't contains the commit"
   
   }


}
```

**Result:**

[image]

2.You could use git command to check if the branch contain the commits.

```
git clone --mirror GitURL

git branch --contains Commitid
```

**Result:**

[image]